# Turning a UIBezierPath into a mask?

Tags: swift, image-processing, uibezierpath, core-image

Not sure if I am asking this question correctly, but I have two components; a `CIImage` and a `UIBezierPath`.  Ideally, I want to create a `CGRect` that encapsulates my `UIBezierPath`; everything inside of the path would be *white*, everything outside of the path would be *black*.  This way, I can then render this `CGRect` to some sort of an image, which I could then use as a mask for other purposes.

I am struggling to figure out how to do this *with a focus on performance*.  My tests, as noted below, leverage using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` which is far too slow for my needs (I will be doing this on sample buffers from a camera).  Therefore, I would like to stick within `CoreImage`.  This is my attempt;

```
// Path
let path = UIBezierPath()
// ... define the path's shape and close it

// My source image
let image = CIImage(cgImage: UIImage(named: "test.jpg")!.cgImage!)

// Renderer
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.extent.size)

// Render path as mask
let img = renderer.image { ctx in
   ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
   ctx.cgContext.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.extent.size.width, height: image.extent.size.height))
   ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
   ctx.cgContext.addPath(path.cgPath)
   ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
}

// Put a filter on the image
let imageFiltered = image.applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectNoir")

// Blend with mask
let maskFilter = CIFilter.blendWithMask()
maskFilter.inputImage = imageFiltered
maskFilter.backgroundImage = image
maskFilter.maskImage = CIImage(cgImage: img.cgImage!)

// Output
if let output = maskFilter.outputImage {
   ... use CIContext() to render back to CVPixelBuffer for preview on MTKView.
}
```

Overall, the goal is to have a defined portion of an image (which will not conform to a traditional shape like a square or circle) which will be filtered with a CIFilter, then composited back over the original.  If there is a better approach (such as somehow taking the original image, filtering it, cropping it to the path (leaving everything outside of the path transparent) and composing, that would likely be better performant.

To note, the above sample code results in a crash as the `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` cannot render the mask fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good so far. I assume the slow part is the generation of the mask image with Core Graphics. Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do the same with Core Image directly (on the GPU). However, you can try the following:

(Assuming from your previous question that the path always has a certain shape,) you can generate a mask image containing the path *once* for a certain reference size of your choice. Make sure that the path doesn't "touch" the border.

Then, when you want to use it as a mask, move and scale the shape image to the correct place using transformations and let its edges extend infinitely (to cover the whole underlying image; that's why the shape shouldn't touch the edges). Something like this:

```
let pathImage = CIImage(cgImage: img.cgImage!)
// scale path to the size of the area you want to mask
var mask = pathImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY))
// move path to the place you want to cover
mask = mask.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: offsetX, y: offsetY))
// let mask fill the rest of the area
mask = mask.clampedToExtent()

// use mask as maskImage...
```

You should be able to recycle the `pathImage` for every frame and thereby avoiding Core Graphics and CPU-GPU-synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for following up!  This was the path I was starting to go down yesterday, hereby creating the path shape once (or even a reference mask image) that could then be scaled/transformed to match the UIBezierPath's shape and size and used accordingly.  Your sample code is helpful to know how to put that into practice and I am going to give this a try ASAP.  Glad I was on the right path but also very grateful for your help!